# associate self.id to nested model before_create in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, many-to-many, polymorphic-associations, rails-models

I have my models & associations currently setup like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
  has_many :versions, :through => :projects
end

class Projects < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :versions
end

class Version < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  attr_accessible :user_id, :project_id
  before_create :associate_user

 def associate_user
  # I have no idea what to do here - in fact, I don't think this is even the right place to do this!
 end
end
```

When I do something like `user.projects.first.versions.create`, I would like the `user_id` field in `Version` to be filled with the `user_id` of the user through whom the model was created. Right now, when I execute that create method, it is set to nil. Now, this makes sense, and I understand *why* it doesnt work. I just cant figure out how to make this work.

I've been scratching my head over this, and cannot figure it out! How would you accomplish this?

**UPDATE**

*Note: although this worked, Levi's answer below is a much, much better solution, and is what I ended up going with*

I figured it out, but I would still like feedback on whether this is the best way to go about this. I feel like there may be a built-in method to rails to do this that I'm missing

Here's my updated `Version` model:

```
class Version < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :production
attr_accessible :user_id, :production_id

after_create :associate_user

def associate_user
    @users = User.all(:include => :productions, :conditions => {"productions_users.production_id" => self.production_id})
    @users.each do |user|
        user.productions.each do |production|
            if production.versions.exists?(self)
                @version_user = user
            end
        end
    end
    self.user_id = @version_user.id
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just pass the id in when you create the version.

```
user.projects.first.version.create(:user_id => user.id)
```

That way you don't need the `before_create` callback at all.

**Edit:**

You may also want to consider your database structure. You have a project_id and a user_id on your versions table. You also have the join table (`projects_users`) with the same keys. Why not turn that into a real model and add a `belongs_to :user_project` (or whatever is appropriate) to the Version model? That is one extra join to go from Versions to Projects, but the data model makes more sense.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_projects
  has_many :projects, :through => :user_projects
  has_many :versions, :through => :projects
end

class UserProject < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :versions
end

class Projects < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :versions
  has_many :user_projects
  has_many :users, :through => :user_projects
end

class Version < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_project
end
```

Comment: This solved my problem perfectly, and is by far a better solution than what I had. I had a feeling that there was a better way, but turning a join table into a real model would have never crossed my mind. Thanks a lot brotha

Comment: I've been using this and its been working perfectly but I am curious about something - My `Version` model doesn't have a `user_project_id` column, but rather a `user_id` and `project_id` column which both get filled in correctly whenever i use the method in your answer. Is rails just automatically figuring this out in the background? In other words, how does rails know to fill those 2 columns??

Comment: That's a good question, and I'm afraid I don't know the answer.